# typeahead in angularjs on clicking the input field

Tags: angularjs, typeahead

I have typeahead for my input field and values are coming from function $scope.skillforJob , when I type A , it gives me skills with appropritate values, eg: Android , Angular Js, Automation testing in dropdown.But I wanted the dropdown with all values, even when no value is typed.By using ng-focus ,it gives me response with all values. But how to display it in my html .

JS:

```
                $scope.skillsforJob = functiond(data){

         $scope.skills =  
                    [{"name":"Android"},
                       {"name":"Angular JS"},
                       {"name":"Automation Testing"},
                         {"name":"BootStrap"},
                         {"name":"C"},
                         {"name":"CSS"},
                         {"name":"Hibernate"}]

}
```

HTML:

```
  <input type="text" name="skills" id="skills" class="form-control"
      autocomplete="off" ng-focus="skillsforJob(model.skills)" placeholder="Skills"
     ng-required="true" ng-model="model.skills"
 typeahead="skills.name for skills in skills | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:10"/>
```

Comment: You can try **angular-chosen** dropdown instead of **typeahead**.

Comment: could you give me similar example.

Comment: Sample angular chosen example [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/I5q9fo?p=preview) link. Please have a look.